# Python:When to use Threads vs. Multiprocessing

Tags: python

What are some good guidelines to follow when deciding to use threads or multiprocessing when speaking in terms of efficiency and code clarity?

Comment: Any good answer needs to mention side effects due to the global interpreter lock when using threads.

Comment: It depends *what* is being done and/or required.

Comment: @Ignacio: Event loops have their caveats, too. Windows' lack of a proper `select()` forces you to use threads in some cross-platform applications.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many of the differences between threading and multiprocessing are not really Python-specific, and some differences are specific to a certain Python implementation.

For CPython, I would use the `multiprocessing` module in either fo the following cases:

- I need to make use of multiple cores simultaneously for performance reasons.  The global interpreter lock (GIL) would prevent any speedup when using threads.  (Sometimes you can get away with threads in this case anyway, for example when the main work is done in C code called via `ctypes` or when using Cython and explicitly releasing the GIL where approriate.  Of course the latter requires extra care.) Note that this case is actually rather rare.  Most applications are not limited by processor time, and if they really are, you usually don't use Python.
- I want to turn my application into a real distributed application later.  This is a lot easier to do for a multiprocessing application.
- There is very little shared state needed between the the tasks to be performed.

In almost all other circumstances, I would use threads.  (This includes making GUI applications responsive.)

Answer (score 6):

For **code clarity**, one of the biggest things is to learn to know and love the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#queue-objects) object for talking between threads (or processes, if using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)... multiprocessing has [its own Queue object](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)).  Queues make things a lot easier and I think enable a lot cleaner code.

I had [a look](http://www.google.ca/search?&q=python+queue+~tutorial) for some decent Queue examples, and this one has some great examples of how to use them and how useful they are (with the exact same logic applying for the multiprocessing Queue):
http://effbot.org/librarybook/queue.htm

For **efficiency**, the details and outcome may not noticeably affect most people, but for python <= 3.1 the implementation for CPython has some interesting (and potentially brutal), efficiency issues on multicore machines that you may want to know about.  These issues involve [the GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).  David Beazley did [a video presentation](http://blip.tv/file/2232410) on it a while back and it is *definitely* worth watching.  More info [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL), including a followup talking about significant improvements on this front in python 3.2.

Basically, my cheap summary of the GIL-related multicore issue is that if you are expecting to get full multi-processor use out of CPython <= 2.7 by using multiple threads, don't be surprised if performance is not great, or even worse than single core.  But if your threads are doing a bunch of i/o (file read/write, DB access, socket read/write, etc), you may not even notice the problem.

The multiprocessing module avoids this potential GIL problem entirely by creating a python interpreter (and GIL) per processor.

Comment: For most Python code, you won't get any speed-up from multiple threads in Python 3.x either -- it just won't be slower any more.

Comment: @Sven: I don't think it is fair to say "most code".  It seriously depends what the code is!  ie: how much time does the code spend waiting for non-python things to complete, during which time another python thread can hum along.  If doing a lot of i/o, working with a GUI, or working with processor heavy C extensions (assuming they release the GIL), threads can make a gigantic difference.  Depending on who you talk to, "most code" includes web servers, in which case [many flavors are threaded to large advantage](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers).

Comment: Coming from parallel number crunching, using threads to do things while another thread is blocking (like in GUI code) isn't exactly what I call [speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) (I mentioned these use cases inmy answer).  And of cause you can get a speedup for processor-heavy C extensions, but that's not exactly what I would call Python code :)  Honestly, you are right, my comment was not very clear.

Comment: does 3.1 remove the GIL or what?