# Python file handling within threads

Tags: python, multithreading, file-io, locking, flush

Hello I have a program that looks through a range of data and finds anomalies in that data. To make my program faster I incorporated the use of threads  (66 in total) now when my program finds the anomalies I would want it to write it to a file but however when i try to write to the file from within multiple threads it wont write.here is a segment of it

Python:

```
import threading

class myThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self,lock,output):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.lock = lock
    self.file = output
def run(self):
    main(self.lock,self.file)

def main(lock,file):
     lock.acquire()
     file.write("It wont write :(")
     lock.release

if __name__ == "__main__":
      lock = threading.Lock()
      file = open("file.txt","wb")
      thread1 = myThread(lock,file)
      thread1.start()
```

here is my code on a much smaller scale
my error message is that file is not open for writing

EDIT:this code for some reason works but my full length code seems to not work so I am going to post it

```
def main(START_IP,END_IP,lock,File):
  # store found DNS servers
  foundDNS=[]

  # scan all the ip addresses in the range
  for i0 in range(START_IP[0], END_IP[0]+1):
      for i1 in range(START_IP[1], END_IP[1]+1):
          for i2 in range(START_IP[2], END_IP[2]+1):
              for i3 in range(START_IP[3], END_IP[3]+1):
                  # build ip addres
                  ipaddr=str(i0)+"."+str(i1)+"."+str(i2)+"."+str(i3)

                  print "Scanning "+ipaddr+"...",
                  # scan address
                  ret=ScanDNS(ipaddr, 10)

                  if ret==True:
                    foundDNS.append(ipaddr)
                    print "Found!"
                    lock.acquire()
                    File.write(ipaddr)
                    File.write("\n")
                    File.flush()
                    lock.release()

                else:
                    print
```

This uses my exact same MyThread class just with the required arguments for main to manipulate the data. If I run my code for about a minute as its scanning over DNS servers
I should get maybe 20-30 DNS servers saved into a file but I generally get this:

FILE.TXT

```
   2.2.1.2
   8.8.8.8
   31.40.40
   31.31.40.40
   31.31.41.41
```

I know for a fact (because I watched the scanning output) and that it hardly all of them. So why is some writing and some not?

Comment: With proper indenting, this code writes successfully for me.

Comment: You know that `multiprocessing` has largely replaced `threading`, right? [Python:When to use Threads vs. Multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710433/pythonwhen-to-use-threads-vs-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 3):

This may be a typo, but this:

```
lock.release
```

should have parentheses:

```
lock.release()
```

Also, your writes will be buffered until the first newline or `flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation for File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file%20flush#file.flush):

> flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk.   Use
>   flush() followed by os.fsync() to ensure this behavior.

`File.fileno()` gets the file descriptor needed by `os.fsync()`:

```
with lock:
    File.write(ipaddr)
    File.write("\n")
    File.flush()
    os.fsync(File.fileno())
```