# Are threads pointless in Python?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, python-3.4

So I need to do some async operations and was thinking about possible solutions. One of those solutions is to use threads to dispatch a work a job and have a callback be called upon completion but upon further reading I came across the Global Interpretor Lock (GIL).

As far as I am aware the GIL effectively makes the CPython single threaded as it blocks all non-running tasks until the other task is complete. If this is the case then why are threads used in Python? Wouldn't it be simpler and more effective to spawn a new process instead which would be able to run in parallel?

I'm just trying to decide whether it is worth the time to use Python threads or whether I should use something else to deal with async operations instead.

Please bear in mind I am using the standard CPython implementation and version 3.4.2 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4710433/3001761 (and the many Related questions on that one)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Doh! Completely missed those. My bad. Thanks for providing a link.